# Boost serialization version information

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

Is there any way to remove the extra 6 bytes that are put in the begin of the serialization data when serializing with Boost Serialization ? I just want to use the serialization mechanism, I don't want any version, object tracking or any other header information.

Comment: I believe the no_header flag to the constructor might do what you want.

Comment: Already tried `no_header` flag and it removes a textual header, but not the 6 extra bytes.

Comment: Maybe you can derive your own archive class and override the void save(const version_type & t) and void load(version_type & t) to be no-ops?  Additionally there are other types for class versions, boost::serialization::item_version_type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem using the [implementation level](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#level):

```
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(MyClass, boost::serialization::object_serializable);
```

By doing this, the serialization will not include the version in front of the raw serialized data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit version information for *all* classes (resulting in a more space efficient, but less robust archive), you can combine the BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION macro with the default behavior:

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {
template <class T>
struct implementation_level_impl< const T >
{
    template<class U>
    struct traits_class_level {
        typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME U::level type;
    };

    typedef mpl::integral_c_tag tag;

    typedef
        BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME mpl::eval_if<
            is_base_and_derived<boost::serialization::basic_traits, T>,
            traits_class_level< T >,
        //else
        BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME mpl::eval_if<
            is_fundamental< T >,
            mpl::int_<primitive_type>,
        //else
        BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME mpl::eval_if<
            mpl::or_<is_class< T >, is_array< T> >,
            mpl::int_<object_serializable>,
        //else
        BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME mpl::eval_if<
            is_enum< T >,
                mpl::int_<primitive_type>,
        //else
            mpl::int_<not_serializable>
        >
        >
        >
        >::type type;
    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(int, value = type::value);
};
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use both:

BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION( , boost::serialization::object_serializable )
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING( , boost::serialization::track_never )

in this order.